How to forward message from the channel to group with wtelegramclient
I found the method in the Telegram API messages.forwardMessages.
Is it possible to use it within the lib wtelegramclient, or is there another way to somehow forward messages through the wtelegramclient?

Please read the library documentation/examples page:
https://wiz0u.github.io/WTelegramClient/EXAMPLES#forward
